# Need some code to which changes the print area based on the last value in column D which isn't -100% after it has been filtered

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to get some code which sets the print area based on the last value in column D which isn't -100% after it has been filtered. See the image to understand what I mean[image: here]

My code currently sorts this data every month by column D, which is the fourth column in this image. I now need it to move the print area (the blue line) to the last row which does not contain -100.0% in Column D, in this case that is the row above (row 145).
Please let me know how this could be automated.

Here is the code:

```
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, wb3 As Workbook, wb4 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet, ws4 As Worksheet, ws5 As Worksheet, ws6 As Worksheet, ws7 As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim value As String
Dim OldDate, NewDate As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

OldDate = Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - 1, 0), "ddmmyy")
NewDate = Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 0), "ddmmyy")


Set wb4 = Workbooks.Open("\\ldnfortunenet\fortunenetdocuments\MAC\IMA\Sector Analysis\Final\IMA Sector Analysis " & OldDate & ".xlsx", 0)
Set ws4 = wb4.Sheets("IMA 20-60")
Set ws5 = wb4.Sheets("IMA 40-85")
Set ws6 = wb4.Sheets("IMA Flexible")
Set ws7 = wb4.Sheets("Look Up Match")



ws4.ListObjects("Table33").Sort.SortFields. _
    Clear
ws4.ListObjects("Table33").Sort.SortFields. _
    Add Key:=Range("Table33[[#All],[YTD Perf]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
    Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ws4.ListObjects("Table33").Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

ws5.ListObjects("Table35").Sort.SortFields. _
    Clear
ws5.ListObjects("Table35").Sort.SortFields. _
    Add Key:=Range("Table35[[#All],[YTD Perf]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
    Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ws5.ListObjects("Table35").Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

ws6.ListObjects("Table3").Sort.SortFields _
    .Clear
ws6.ListObjects("Table3").Sort.SortFields _
    .Add Key:=Range("Table3[[#All],[YTD Perf]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
    Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ws6.ListObjects("Table3").Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: i've added it to the original post. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?:

```
Sub Jeremys_Macro()
Dim RHS_Column As String

Range("XFD1").End(xlToLeft).Activate
RHS_Column = Mid(ActiveCell.Address, 2, WorksheetFunction.Find("$", Right(ActiveCell.Address, Len(ActiveCell.Address) - 1)) - 1) ' Find the last column

Range("D1048576").End(xlUp).Activate 'Finds the bottom row
Do Until ActiveCell.Value <> 1 And ActiveCell.Value <> -1 ' loops until the cell isn't 100% *OR* -100% (I didn't know if it was 100% or -100% - the screenshot suggests it's minus)
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1).Activate
Loop

ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:" & RHS_Column & ActiveCell.Row).Address

End Sub
```

Comment: it didn't hit the row i wanted it to, but some rows below. Also the last column on the right will always be AC, so don't need to use the RHS_column line. I think just the last line needs to be edited?

Comment: I've changed it so it should go to the right row now.. I just left the RHS_column line in (just in case) - it won't cause any issues for you so if the columns do change in future, it'll pick that up for you.

Comment: If you do want to remove it then just delete the "Dim" line, the RHS_column line and in the bottom line just change the ..."Range("A1:" & RHS_Column & ActiveCell.Row)"... to "Range("A1:AC" & ActiveCell.Row)"